# Shoppe category routing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm stuck with a little problem with displaying Shoppe categories. I want the category name and image displayed on my index page, category name acts as a link to the category page, where products of this category are displayed. I have the following code in my view:

```
<% @products.each do |category, products| %>
    <%=  link_to category.name, product_category_path %>
<% end %>
```

but it returns me an error `undefined local variable or method 'product_category_path' for #<#<Class:0xb22076fc>:0xb2205870>`

should I make a controller for categories, as well as for products? Because now I have only `products_controller.rb` with the following code:

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
    def index
        @products = Shoppe::Product.root.ordered.includes(:product_categories, :variants)
        @products = @products.group_by(&:product_category)
    end
    def show
        @product = Shoppe::Product.root.find_by_permalink(params[:permalink])
    end
end
```

Comment: Could you please see 'rake routes' and see if you are using the correct route helper path

Comment: u should be fine just passing a category id `<%=  link_to category.name, product_category_path(category.id) %>`

Answer (score 0):

I am unclear about what do you want to achieve here, but the error message is very clear. if you run `rake routes` you won't find a path called `product_category_path`

you need to put

```
resources :products do
  resources :categories
end
```

in your `routes.rb` file, and you need to create a `CategoriesController`  with `show` action

the reason I am confused is

```
<%=  link_to category.name, product_category_path %>
```

`product_category_path` means you want a url like this

```
/products/:product_id/categories/:id(.:format)
```

and you have to use `product_category_path(product, category)`

but it does fit your description of what you want to do. what your really want might be just simple `category_path`, in that case you can access a category page with all products belongs to it like this

```
/categories/:id(.:format)
```

and for you view, you can do

```
<%=  link_to category.name, category_path(category) %>
```

you still need to create `CategoriesController` with `action`, but it will not ask for `product_id`

the controller code may look like this(assume you set up the association correctly)

```
class CategoriesController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @category = Category.includes(:products).find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

Comment: this is what I have within `rake routes`: `product_category GET /product_categories/:id(.:format) shoppe/product_categories#show`

Comment: @AlexNikolaev94 `shoppe/product_categories#show` tells rails to look for `Shoppe::ProductCategories` controller and call `show` action there. If I understand your code correctly, you have `product_categories` joint table. It is uncommon to have view for joint model and it doesn't sound necessary in your case.

Comment: @Zhiliang Takuto Xing Your solution is sound, but it also depends on the use case. What if `show` action for categories needs to be different view which doesn't have any products, but just information about that category? I think using member routes will set the application up to be more easily changed in the future if need be.

Answer (score 0):

I think the *railsy* way would be to:

**1) Create CategoriesController**

**2) Use Member routes**

In your routes:

```
resources :categories do
  member do
    get :products
  end
end
```

Your helper will then be `products_category_path(@category)`, and the url will be `/categories/:id/products`.

A member route adds a custom action `products` to your controller.

Your index view would have this:

```
<% @products.each do |product| %>
  <%=  link_to product.category.name, products_category_path(product.category) %>
<% end %>
```

In `CategoriesController` you would have:

```
def products
  Shoppe::Product.where(category_id: params[:id])
end
```

N.B. Include products' categories in your products index action to avoid N+1 queries